# How to integrate slack bot in any slack room?

Tags: slack-api

I have developed Slack bot based on following existing library provided by Slack.

https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-client

Currently, this bot only works on the team that is created on.

Is there any way to submit this `bot` with the `slack app` so that any team can integrate this bot into their room?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with adding your bot to https://api.slack.com/community - click the "get in touch" link and let them know you made it - after a while your bot should be added to that list.